# Как исправить ошибку: error expected expression before

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//односвязный список

typedef struct gms_t
{
    int data;   //дата
    int temp_vozducha;  //температура воздуха
    int temp_vodi;  //температура воды
    int atm_davl;   //атмосферное давление
    struct gms_t* next    //указатель на следующий элемент
}gms;

typedef gms* pelem; //тип-указатель
pelem HEAD = NULL; //"голова" списка
int NN = 0; //текущее количество элементов
int N_MAX = 10; //максимум списка

int main()
{
    int menu;
        puts("\n Menu :");
        puts("\n1) Dobavlenie elementa.");
        puts("\n2) Redaktirovanie.");
        puts("\n3) Udalenie elementa.");
        puts("\n4) Sortirovka po polju temperatura vozduha.");
        puts("\n5) Vyvod vseh dannyh.");
        puts("\n6) Formirovanie spiska jelementov s temperaturoj vody nizhe zadanogo znachenija.");
        puts("\n7) Vyvod daty s maksimal'noj temperaturoj vozduha i vody.");
        puts("\n8) Formirovanie spiska jelementov s atmosfernym davleniem vyshe 760 mm rt.st..");
        puts("\n0) THE END");
    do
    {
            printf("\nVvedite nomer zadachi : ");
            scanf("%d",&menu);
    switch(menu)
        {
      case 1 : ad();break;
      case 2 : ed(pelem p); break;
      case 3 : del(char obj_data[]); break;
      case 4 : sort(); break;
      case 5 : rd(pelem p); break;
    default:
             if (menu!=0)
                  puts("\n\n \t\tVveden nepravil'nyj nomer zadachi!");        }    }
 while (menu!=0);
        puts("\n ********THE END******** \n");
    return 0;
}
pelem ad() //добавление элемента
{
   pelem neo = (pelem) malloc(sizeof(gms));
   //добавление элемента в начало
   if (HEAD == NULL)
   {
      HEAD = neo;
      neo->next = NULL;
   }
   else
   {
      neo->next = HEAD;
      HEAD = neo;
   }
   NN++;
   if (NN < N_MAX)
         {
            pelem p = ad();
            ed(p);
         }
         else
         {
            printf("List is full\n");
         }
   return neo;
}

void ed(pelem p) //редактирование элемента
{
   pelem ad();
   //ввод данных
   gms dan;
   printf("Data: ");
   scanf("%d", &dan.data);

   printf("Temperatura vodi: ");
   scanf("%d", &dan.temp_vodi);

   printf("Temperatura vozducha: ");
   scanf("%d", &dan.temp_vozducha);

   printf("Atmosphere davlenie : ");
   scanf("%d", &dan.atm_davl);

   dan.next = p->next;
   *p = dan;

   system("cls");
   char obj[40];
         printf("Edit object : ");
         scanf("%s", obj);
         if (HEAD)
         {
            pelem p = find(obj);
            if (p)
            {
               ed(p);
            }
         }
         else
         {
            printf("List is empty\n");
         }
}
void rd(pelem p)  //чтение элемента
{
   int i;
   if (p)
   {
      for (i = 0; i < 80; i++)
      {
         printf("_");
      }
      printf("\n");

      printf("Data: %d\n", p->data);
      printf("Temperatura vodi: %d\n", p->temp_vodi);
      printf("Temperatura vozducha: %d\n", p->temp_vozducha);
      printf("Atmosphere davlenie: %d\n", p->atm_davl);

      for (i = 0; i < 80; i++)
      {
         printf("_");
      }
      printf("\n");
      pelem p = HEAD;
         if (p == NULL)
         {
            printf("List is empty\n");
         }
         else
            while (p != NULL)
            {
               rd(p);
               p = p->next;
            }
   }
}

pelem find(char obj_data[])  //поиск элемента
{
   pelem p = HEAD;
   do
   {
      if (!strcmp(p->data, obj_data))
      {
         return p;
      }
      p = p->next;
   }
   while (p);
   printf("Ne naydenu\n");
   return p;
}

void del(char obj_data[])
{
   if (HEAD)
   {
      pelem p = find(obj_data);
      if (p)
      {
         if (p == HEAD) //если голова - и есть искомый объект
         {
            if (NN > 1)
            {
               HEAD = HEAD->next;
            }
            else
            {
               HEAD = NULL;
            }
         }
         else
         {
            pelem father = HEAD;
            while (father->next != p)
            {
               father = father->next;
            }
            father->next = p->next;
         }
         free(p);
         NN--;
         printf("Udaleno: %s\n", obj_data);
         char obj[40];
         printf("Delete item : ");
         scanf("%s", obj);
         if (HEAD)
         {
            del(obj);
         }
         else
         {
            printf("List is empty\n");
         }
         return;
      }
   }
}
void sort()  //сортировка
{
   int j;
   for (j = 0; j < NN; j++)
   {
      pelem p = HEAD;
      pelem son = p->next;
      if (p->temp_vozducha < son->temp_vozducha)
      {
         p->next = son->next;
         HEAD = son;
         son->next = p;
      }
      p = HEAD;
      while ((p->next)->next)
      {
         pelem father = p;
         p = p->next;
         pelem son = p->next;
         if (p->temp_vozducha < son->temp_vozducha)
         {
            father->next = son;
            p->next = son->next;
            son->next = p;
         }
         p = father->next;
      }
      sort();
         pelem p = HEAD;
         if (p == NULL)
         {
            printf("List is empty\n");
         }
         else
            while (p != NULL)
            {
               rd(p);
               p = p->next;
            }
      }
   }
   while (c != '0');
   }
}
/*int main()
{
   char c;
   do
   {
      printf("Menu\n"
             "Count: %d/%d\n"
             "[1] add\n"
             "[2] list\n"
             "[3] edit\n"
             "[4] delete\n"
             "[5] sort\n"
             "[0] exit\n"
             ">>", NN, N_MAX);

      c = getch();
      system("cls");
      if (c == '1') //добавление элемента
      {
         if (NN < N_MAX)
         {
            pelem p = ad();
            ed(p);
         }
         else
         {
            printf("List is full\n");
         }
      }
      if (c == '2') //просмотр списка
      {
         pelem p = HEAD;
         if (p == NULL)
         {
            printf("List is empty\n");
         }
         else
            while (p != NULL)
            {
               rd(p);
               p = p->next;
            }
      }
      if (c == '3')
      {
         char obj[40];
         printf("Edit object : ");
         scanf("%s", obj);
         if (HEAD)
         {
            pelem p = find(obj);
            if (p)
            {
               ed(p);
            }
         }
         else
         {
            printf("List is empty\n");
         }
      }
      if (c == '4')
      {
         char obj[40];
         printf("Delete item : ");
         scanf("%s", obj);
         if (HEAD)
         {
            del(obj);
         }
         else
         {
            printf("List is empty\n");
         }
      }

      if (c == '5')
      {
         sort();
         pelem p = HEAD;
         if (p == NULL)
         {
            printf("List is empty\n");
         }
         else
            while (p != NULL)
            {
               rd(p);
               p = p->next;
            }
      }
   }
   while (c != '0');

   return 0;
}*/
```

Comment: может, вы для начала приведете эту порнографию в человеческий вид?

Comment: @belochka, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора. Хотя все равно вряд ли кто-то будет вчитываться в эту простыню.

Answer (score 3):

Не обломался и вчитался :)

Учитесь читать то, что вам пишет компилятор. Первая же строка:

```
main.cpp(15) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
//...
```

говорит о том, что на строке 15 не хватает ; перед }. Посмотрим:

```
//...
    struct gms_t* next    //указатель на следующий элемент
}gms;
//...
```

Действительно, не хватает. Исправляем (после `next` поставьте `;`), снова компилируем. Следующая ошибка:

```
main.cpp(41) : error C3861: 'ad': identifier not found
```

Компилятор не знает, что такое ad. Смотрю на код. Оказывается, это функция, но она определена ниже, чем используется. Тут есть 2 варианта:

1. переместить **определение** функции ad() до функции, откуда ad() вызывается (это main()).
2. Оставить все определения функций на своих местах. Добавить **объявление** функции ad() до вызова.

Пойдем по второму пути. Заодно объявим другие функции, которые будут вызваны выше, чем определены:

```
// объявления функций
pelem ad();
void ed(pelem p);
void del(char obj_data[]);
void sort();
void rd(pelem p);

int main()
{
//...
```

Следующая ошибка:

```
main.cpp(49) : error C2275: 'pelem' : illegal use of this type as an expression
```

Посмотрите на 49-ю строку:

```
  case 2 : ed(pelem p); break;
```

Зачем тут тип `pelem`? Типичная ошибка программирования методом copy-paste. Исправляем это и такую же ошибку на 50й и 52й строках:

```
  case 1 : ad();break;
  case 2 : ed(p); break;
  case 3 : del(obj_data); break;
  case 4 : sort(); break;
  case 5 : rd(p); break;
```

Дальше.

```
main.cpp(49) : error C2065: 'p' : undeclared identifier
```

Наверное, название переменной `p` тоже осталось после copy-paste. Судя по коду функции `ed(pelem p)`, Вы планируете изменить элемент списка. Но какой? Сперва пытаетесь вызывать функцию ad(), но делаете это неправильно.

```
void ed(pelem p) //редактирование элемента
{
pelem ad();
```

Тип возвращаемого значения тут уже не нужен. А то, что функция возвращает, вы не используете.

Дальше читаю код:

```
pelem ad() //добавление элемента
{
   pelem neo = (pelem) malloc(sizeof(gms));
```

И тут пламенный порыв помочь новичку угасает навсегда. Срочно бегите к семинаристу, посыпайте голову пеплом, и признайтесь ему, что не понимаете синтаксиса языка C++, не знаете, как работает `malloc`. Попросите дополнительно позаниматься с Вами!!!

Comment: Хороший обзор, а вот сломались Вы из-за typedef-ов и возможности выбрасывать слово struct.

На самом-то деле malloc нормальный. Т.е. это

    struct gms *neo = (struct gms *)malloc(sizeof(struct gms));

Comment: Я тоже не удержался и почитал этот код. 

Проблемы к сожалению не в синтаксических ошибках и пропущенных объявлениях.

Диагноз неутешительный - алгоритмическая каша. Чего стоят одни лишь рекурсивные вызовы.

Comment: И правда! Это мне надо голову пеплом посыпать :)